# Не могу понять как записать модуль в основной файл

Tags: python

Есть 2 файла. Основной и файл с модулями. В файле с модулями записаны функции добавления товара и удаления товара. Не могу понять как записать эти модули в основной файл. Почти всегда выводит ошибку:

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'add_product'
```

Вот пример кода: Основной файл:

```
import store
shop = {
    'мучное' :{
        'пряники':100
    },
    'молочное': { 'сыр': 200}
}

store = open('store', 'w', encoding='utf-8')


store.add_product()
```

файл с модулями:

```
def add_product(group, product, price,shop):
    if group in shop:
        if product not in shop[group]:
            shop[group].update({product:price})
        else:
            print('Такой продукт есть')
    else:
        print('Группы нет')



def del_product(group, product,shop):
    if group in shop:
        if product in shop[group]:
            return shop[group].pop(product)
        else:
            print('Такого продукта нету')
    else:
        print('Такого раздела в магазине нету')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import store
# ...
store = open('store', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
store.add_product()
```

Не делайте так. Вы тут вызываете метод `add_product` объекта `file`, а не своего модуля `store`.

Старайтесь не называть свои переменные так же, как называются ваши модули, встроенные модули, функции и объекты питона. Это очень частая причина "странных" ошибок.